# Facebook library project is showing error but there is no error inside the project

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to run one of my old android project (Eclipse project).
It uses Facebook lib, google-play-services-lab and android-maps-util-master.
Both Facebook lib and my project MyanmarWatch_ is showing red ! on them.
I don't know how to fix since I don't see any error within them.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got solution. I just forgot to check Java Build Path. 2 jar files are missing and I imported them.
[image]